What is the difference between plausibility and probability, and can we argue for the former without the latter?
If I want to argue that hypothesis  is more plausible (i.e., more worthy of credence) than hypothesis , I could frame this using Bayesian inference given some evidence  by showing that
(∣)⋅() > (∣)⋅().
There are, however, several points worth noting:

This approach relies on probabilities, effectively reducing the concept of plausibility to that of probability.
The comparison depends on prior probabilities () and (), which can feel recursive because it seems to assume we already have an idea of which hypothesis seems more plausible to us before considering the evidence, but the whole point of the exercise is to calculate plausibility in the first place.
Additionally, applying probabilities in certain contexts can seem problematic or out of place, particularly in domains where we lack the ability to develop statistics to validate whether the real world aligns with our probability estimates. For instance, when evaluating the plausibility of competing metaphysical worldviews (see related question), we lack a "metaphysical simulator" to generate frequencies for how often worldview  versus  might be true.

This raises the question: are there situations in which plausibility carries a meaning that cannot be fully captured by or reduced to the concept of probability? If so, how do philosophers suggest arguing for plausibility without relying on probabilities?
Or am I overthinking this, and plausibility and probability are essentially interchangeable concepts?

Closely related questions:

What is the difference between a probability and a possibility?
Is plausibility more fundamental than probability?
How does one “measure” the plausibility of theories with no direct evidence?


@Lowri I'm not asking how imagination plays a role in the prior of Bayesian inference. I'm asking about the conceptual difference between probability and plausibility.

The question is raised, but to what end?

@user80226 now you know how it feels like when people here accuse you of posing duplicates when it’s not really a duplicate, and they’re lazily just finding anything remotely similar to your question to try to shut it down ;)

In my usage, plausible means not-unlikely; probable means likely. What confidence threshhold consitutes "likely" varies from case to case. But this is a linguistic answer, not a philosophy answer.

Well, mission accomplished. I was going to say, the only person I know who casually used the word 'plausible' was a Lawyer. He also used 'liable to' to mean "having a tendency to". But, you have asked lots of fairly well-received questions.

There is an entire section on the SEP where they discuss various different approaches to model uncertainty and inferences under certainty. In the mapping listed, probability is a form of plausibility relation. It is a way to try to capture what is plausible using mathematical figures. As such, plausibility is arguably more fundamental than probability.

This can be practically seen in the area of theory choice. Scientists regularly choose between theories by virtue of epistemic values such as explanatory scope, explanatory power, simplicity, etc. They do this without attaching Bayesian probabilities to different hypotheses.
See this article here for more on this.

A conceptual gap in your answer is that you haven't successfully established an explicit link between the diagram in the first linked SEP article (which I edited into your answer for convenience) and the epistemic values in your second linked SEP article. The first article never mentions epistemic values. Can you please clarify?

More concretely, do epistemic values fall under "Ranking Functions", "Possibility Functions (Fuzzy Logic)", "Probability Functions", "Qualitative Probability Relations", or what? And why?
